# Libcurl c++ Segmentation fault (core dumped) in linux

Tags: c++, libcurl

I have written a code, which work very well in windows (VS 2017). But now i tried to convert it for Linux. First request is done successfully but the second one throw segmentation fault.

This is my write callback function. (I think here is a issue)

```
size_t callback(
        const char* in,
        size_t size,
        size_t num,
        string* out)
    {
        const size_t totalBytes(size * num);
        out->clear();
        out->append(in, totalBytes);

        return totalBytes;
    }
```

here is my send messages functions.

```
CURL* initMessageSend(string* auth_token) {
    CURL *hnd = curl_easy_init();

    string token = "Authorization: bearer " + *auth_token;

    curl_easy_setopt(hnd, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
    curl_easy_setopt(hnd, CURLOPT_URL, "https://oauth.reddit.com/api/compose");

    struct curl_slist *headers = NULL;
    headers = curl_slist_append(headers, "cache-control: no-cache");
    headers = curl_slist_append(headers, "User-Agent: cpp/c");
    headers = curl_slist_append(headers, "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    headers = curl_slist_append(headers, token.c_str());
    curl_easy_setopt(hnd, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, headers);

    curl_easy_setopt(hnd, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, callback);

    return hnd;
}

void sendMessage(string* auth_token, string username,string subject) {

    CURL* hnd = initMessageSend(auth_token);
while (1) {
        char ch = getch();

        if (ch == 's') {
            string msg = "";
            cout << "\n\nEnter Message:";

            getline(cin, msg);

            msg = "to=" + username + "&text=" + msg + "&subject=" + subject;
            curl_easy_setopt(hnd, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, msg.c_str());

            CURLcode ret = curl_easy_perform(hnd);

            if (ret == CURLE_OK) {
                cout << "(sent)";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The first request to get the token is successful but when sending the message it give me Segmentation Fault.

Comment: That's not the correct signature for a callback function.

Comment: And do you set the [user data](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_WRITEDATA.html) for the callback anywhere?

Comment: No i did not set any user data, kindly tell me the correct signature!

Comment: It's in [the documentation](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION.html) - the first argument isn't `const` and the last one is a `void *`.

Comment: i remove const from first argument, there is no luck. secondly i need to convert the response to string so cant convert the last argument to void*.

Comment: If you are not willing to supply a callback with the correct signature, why do you expect things to work?

Answer (score 0):

Just make sure you installed:

```
  # shell script
    $ sudo apt-get install libcurl-dev
```